# JQuery display XSLT into my html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xslt

Can someone help me with this please? 
basically I am trying to display the result of my transformed XSLT into an existing page, the transformation seem to be working, but it's not displaying the results when I run my html page. I have tried to run the XSL independently and it's seem to display correctly on his own, so that will leave me with jQuery.

Thank you

This is my code:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
  displayResult();
});

function loadXMLDoc(filename)
{
var deferred = $.Deferred();
var promise = deferred.promise();

 $.ajax({
    url: filename,
    type: 'get',
    dataType: 'xml',
    success: function(data) {
        console.log("resolved");
        deferred.resolve(data);

    }, error :function(v1, v2) 

 });
 return promise;

}

 function displayResult(){
 var xmlPromise = loadXMLDoc("my.xml");
 var xslPromise = loadXMLDoc("my.xsl");

 $.when(xmlPromise, xslPromise).done(function(xml, xsl){
  if (document.implementation && document.implementation.createDocument)
  {
    var xsltProcessor = new XSLTProcessor();
    xsltProcessor.importStylesheet(xsl);
    var resultDocument = xsltProcessor.transformToFragment(xml, document);
    $('#example').append(resultDocument);
  } else if (window.ActiveXObject)
  {
    /* IE */
    var ex = xml.transformNode(xsl);
    $('#example').innerHTML = ex;
   }
 });
}
```

Comment: There seems to be at least one problem with your code on the line `}, error :function(v1, v2)`. Your error handling function is not properly defined. Either remove it entirely by deleting `, error :function(v1, v2)` or add `{}` to make it syntaxically correct.

Comment: Hi Nicolas, sorry was away and only got your reply now, thank you for that, but that doesn't solve my initial problem.

Comment: I've just tried your example and it actually works. Have you checked that your XSL has `<xsl:output method="html">`?

Comment: Yes, you're right, the problem was in a different method on my javaScript file, that was breaking everything. I was only looking at this particular method.

Comment: Thank you a lot, you did help me to spot the real problem.